# Uploaded video on Google Drive constantly previews with "Whoops! There was a problem playing this video"

Tags: google-drive, video

I'm trying to share a video directly with one person and every single format I upload in displays this error. What format do you need to properly preview videos on Drive?

Comment: I suggest uploading it to YouTube instead, without making the video public. You can keep videos private on YouTube, and it is excellent at saving and playing videos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually has nothing to do with formats. Google Drive appears to have a bug when trying to use multiple Google accounts on the same machine through the dropdown list, e.g. uploading to the drive of your personal gmail account when you have a different work account that you use 90% of the time. You can tell this is the case because clicking through to the video itself will give you a 403 error even when you have proper credentials.

1. The easiest solution is use incognito mode, sign in and you'll see the video properly previewing. It's actually not a video format problem at all.
2. Alternatively, you can sign out of all accounts other than the one that you need for drive.